# Error writing XML File in Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to write a series of values to an XML 1.0 file with several different data types. I try to write a string value that is an integer and I get an invalid character error. However, when I write a string value that is a double, it executes without a problem.

```java
Element hp = doc.createElement("HP");
stats.appendChild(hp);

//This causes an error
hp.appendChild(doc.createElement(Integer.toString(/*Some int*/)));

Element weight = doc.createElement("Weight");
stats.appendChild(weight);

//This runs just fine
weight.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(Double.toString(/*Some double*/)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the `double`, you are creating a `TextNode`, which as the name suggests, can take any text value. So there is no issue there.

When you are using the `int`, you are creating an `Element` whose tag name is the value passed to it, which in this case is an `int`. However, element names must begin with a letter or an underscore, not a number.

Comment: Oh crud, I didn't even notice I did that... That would be why.